# I want to be able to connect two of my assistants in IBM watson

Tags: javascript, html, json, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I am trying to connect two af my assistants in IBM Watson under the same account. I have tried to call on the workspace ID of the one assistant from the other, but I am not sure if I am doing it right. Has somebody gotten any ideas?

I want the assistant on my page to understand if he does not have the material the person is asking for to search the other assistants.

Comment: Please share details, so that your actual question becomes clear. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I believe this might help, it describes how to use multiple assistants https://medium.com/ibm-watson/im-watson-let-me-transfer-you-to-watson-5c3c46f1b59c